# read csv with escape characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with some text, among others. I want to tokenize (split into a list of words) this text and am having problems with how `pd.read_csv` interprets escape characters.

My csv file looks like this:

```
text, number
one line\nother line, 12
```

and the code is like follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
word_tokenize(df.iloc[0,0])
```

output is:

```
['one', 'line\\nother', 'line']
```

while what I want is:

```
['one', 'line', 'other', 'line']
```

The problem is `pd.read_csv()` is not interpreting the `\n` as a newline character but as two characters (`\` and `n`).

I've tried setting the `escapechar` argument to `'\'` and to `'\\'` but both just remove the slash from the string without doing any interpretation of a newline character, i.e. the string becomes `on one linenon other line`.

If I explicitly set `df.iloc[0,0] = 'one line\nother line'`, `word_tokenize` works just fine, because `\n` is actually interpreted as a newline character this time.

Ideally I would do this simply changing the way `pd.read_csv()` interprets the file, but other solutions are also ok.

Comment: Neither example has `\n`. All your examples have single `\` (read text has it escaped, of course), yet you say all the time that it's `\n` (e.g. "If I explicitly set df.iloc[0,0] = 'one line\other line', word_tokenize works just fine, because \n is actually interpreted as a newline character this time." - but the string doesn't have `\n` anywhere???) Please correct this and specify what you want (`\n` or `\` to work as newline).

Comment: you can iterate through your output and do a `split('\')` wich will split a string into two if their is the char '\' in it.
more info : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/
But this is not very optimal

Comment: @h4z3 Corrected all `\ ` in the text to `\n` as they were supposed to be. I want the `\n` to be interpreted as a newline.

Comment: Ok. It loads the text and escaped backslash so that it's literally the same thing as loaded (not converted to newline). For it to become just a newline, you'd need to substitute double backslash for one. If you print your whole array, it will be `['one', 'line\nother', 'line']` but if you print list[1] manually, it will interpret the newline - just like you want in your comment. But your post says to split on `\n`, which is a different thing...

Comment: Tbh to read this as a real csv (where new line means new row), I'd probably read the whole thing as a normal text file (e.g. by lines in a loop), replace double backslash with single, then interpret the whole thing as csv (with or without saving in between, depending on size and how you deal with original file and replacing) - two "rows" that were previously separated by text `\n` rather than physical newline should be now separated by physical newlines and therefore interpreted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit poorly worded.  I guess `pandas` escaping the `\` in the string is confusing `nltk.word_tokenize`.  `pandas.read_csv` can only use one separator (or a regex, but I doubt you want that), so it will always read the text column as `"one line\nother line"`, and escape the backslash to preserve it.  If you want to further parse and format it, you could use converters.  Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv(
         "file.csv", converters={"text":lambda s: re.split("\\\\n| ", s)}
)
```

The above results to:

```
                       text   number
0  [one, line, other, line]       12
```

**Edit:** In case you need to use `nltk` to do the splitting (say the splitting depends on the language model), you would need to unescape the string before passing on to `word_tokenize`; try something like this:

```
lambda s: word_tokenize(s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

**Note:** Matching lists in queries is incredibly tricky, so you might want to convert them to tuples by altering the lambda like this:

```
lambda s: tuple(re.split("\\\\n| ", s))
```

Comment: Edited question, what was just a `\ ` in the string should have been a `\n`. `word_tokenize` is from `nltk`

Comment: In that case you can update the regex to `"\\\\n| "`, and it should work (updated in my answer).

Comment: @Kaio I added a few extra notes, maybe it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In you case simply use:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\\,', names=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], engine='python')
```

Comment: That does not work, I have other fields that are comma separated. Column names are already given in first line of file.

Comment: @Kaio Then you need to use regex with python engine. I updated my code

Comment: Still does not work, I get a lot of NaNs in my DataFrame. See example file I gave.

Comment: @Kaio I don't see any file

Comment: the contents of it are in the first "code box" in the question. Also I already accepted an answer, maybe look in the better worded version I make [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326916/read-csv-with-newline-escape-sequence)

Comment: @Kaio but there is no NaN data. Provide a large example of data

Comment: running the code given by you on my file gives a lot of NaN because of the`names=[...]` part.

Comment: @Kaio simply attach you file, then i see what is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194005/discussion-between-kaio-and-zaraki-kenpachi).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\\', " "))
print(df.iloc[1, 0])

# output: one line other line
```