# read csv with newline escape sequence

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with some text, among others. I want the escape sequences to be interpreted (e.g. `\n` should be interpreted as a newline) for a following part of the code. `pd.read_csv` is reading in these text columns without interpreting the `\n` as a line break but as two separate chars in the string, i.e. saving it as `'\\'` and `'n'`.

My csv file looks like this (first line with column names):

```sh
text, number
one line\nother line, 12
second text\nwith more words maybe, 13
```

and it is read in with `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`.

I've tried setting the escapechar argument to '\' but it just removes the slash from the string without doing any interpretation of a newline character, i.e. the first string becomes `one linenother line`.

output like it is:

```sh
In[]: df.iloc[0,0]
'one line\\nother line'
In[]: print(df.iloc[0,0])
one line\nother line
```

while what I want is:

```sh
In[]: df.iloc[0,0]
'one line\nother line'
In[]: print(df.iloc[0,0])
one line
other line
```

If I explicitly set `df.iloc[0,0] = 'one line\nother line'`, I get the expected behaviour, because \n is actually interpreted as a newline character this time.

Ideally I would do this simply changing the way pd.read_csv() interprets the file, but other solutions are also ok.

PS: I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323221/read-csv-with-escape-characters/56323597#56323597) but it was not worded correctly and instead of changing the question I accepted a given answer (because it answered the question I had asked, but not what I wanted to solve), and asked this new question.

Comment: It looks like you have some missing info on your **csv** in your example you don't have any **number** present in the first line am I correct ?

Comment: First line are the column names, it gets picked up correctly by `pd.read_csv`

Comment: I meant the second line should be **one line, ###number###\n**

Comment: No, in the example there would be a first field/column of text with some escape sequences, and then another field/column with numbers. So, two lines and two columns are given in the example, columns are correctly comma separated. I only gave the numbers to show that there is more in this DataFrame than just the text.

Comment: Did you ever managed to solve it?